# Get active directory id from web api request originated from python

Tags: c#, python, asp.net-web-api

I'm able to get the IP address from the web api request, but I'm wondering if there is a way to get the active directory or directory services id from a web api request originated from python?

The following will echo out the users IP address. How can I make a call from python that would allow me to echo out their AD or DS id?

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Get(string system)
 {
            // validate ip address
            string ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;

return new HttpResponseMessage() 
            { 
                Content = new StringContent(ip)
            };
}
```

Comment: You do realize that Python doesn't really care about AD, right? Unless you know that the request is coming from a Windows machine, and Python has a library installed that can operate with AD, you won't be able to get these information.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?(You must add a reference to System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll)

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string system)
{

  string domain = new System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain).ConnectedServer; 

  return new HttpResponseMessage()  {   Content = new StringContent(domain )   };
}
```